# Ruby performance of File.read

Tags: ruby, string, performance, io

Given the following script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'benchmark'

response = open('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=skateboarding+dog')

outside = Benchmark.measure do
  response_body = response.read
  10000.times do
    response_body.scan(/dog/)
  end
end

inside = Benchmark.measure do
  10000.times do
    response.read.scan(/dog/)
  end
end

puts [outside, inside].map(&:utime).inspect
```

I get the following result:

```
[1.25, 0.06000000000000005]
```

Why does reading the file every time perform about 20x better?

In case my system info matters:

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because after your first test, `response` is read to the end, and in each iteration of the second test, the result of `read` is trivial, which saves time, and it also returns mere empty string. So the `scan` also ends fast.

```
irb> response.read.scan(/dog/)
=> ["dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog"]
irb> response.read.scan(/dog/)
=> []
```

Comment: `open('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=skateboarding+dog').read.scan(/dog/)
=> ["dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog"]`

Comment: @Kaleidoscope the point is that `read` moves the read pointer of the response (which acts as stream). When you call `read` the second time, it returns the empty string.